# How to change the spacing values in a python mayavi object?

Tags: python, 3d, contour, mayavi, mayavi.mlab

I have plotted a few things using mlab in Python mayavi. For some reason, when I create an isosurface by doing:

```
s = mlab.contour3d(xx, yy, zz, data, contours=[1.5], figure=fig)
```

it creates one with a spacing (0, 0, 0.5) when it should be (0.5, 0.5, 0.5). How do I set that spacing in my script without having to manually go into the figure's pipeline (show below)?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6Gt2.png)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out myself by doing:

```
fig.children[-1].spacing = np.array([0.5, 0.5, 0.5])
```